# Image Stitching of images without overlapping region using opencv python

Tags: image, python-3.x, opencv, image-stitching

I want to stitch images which are not having any overlapping region.I am using OpenCV with Python. They are not having common key points and features.So, I can not use features for Image stitching.I am attaching the images which I need to stitch.Link for folder of the images: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8MKTEMDgNb3Zy1pSWVmazlxa2s?usp=sharing

Comment: Will these images necessarily be bordering each other and you simply need to find out how much to push them up or down until they align? And are you looking to do this manually for these two images or in general with automation? Also there is a *little bit* of overlap between those images. Since you won't get many (if any) features from that tiny bit, you can chop the ends off each image and use *direct* image matching instead of keypoint matching through Lucas-Kanade. Or if you're sure there's only translation involved, through simple template matching.

Comment: With the little bit of overlap that these images *do* have, it *is* possible to match them. Do you know if your images in the folder will always have some small amount of overlap like this, or is that not guaranteed?

Comment: I want to do this task automatically and  I am not sure that there is only translation involved.

Comment: Again, do you know if the images *will* have some small overlap like these do? And do you know which side that overlap will be on? (I.e. if these are sequential images)

Comment: Yes, I will know the side which will overlap and I can't say something about small overlap

Comment: Then if the images mostly look like this, I think you're doomed. The best thing to try would be aligning images based on *assumed* features, such as lines in the first image align to lines in the second, but you would have to have well defined lines for that; same with other shapes. So I don't think you can do what you want to do. Of course, if you had the flight path you could align with satellite or other aerial imagery.